# Data couldn't retrieve out from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my connection to database

```
<?php

    // this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
    error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
    // but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.

    define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
    define('DBUSER', 'root');
    define('DBPASS', '');
    define('DBNAME', 'dbtest');

    $conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
    $dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);

    if ( !$conn ) {
        die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
    }

    if ( !$dbcon ) {
        die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
    }
```

this is the simple code to retrieve the data out from database

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$query="SELECT * FROM `users`";
if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query))
{
echo "query executed<br>";
while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_array($is_query_run));
 {
    echo 'sql is running';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$query_execute['userName'].'</td><td>'.$query_execute['userEmail'].'</td></tr';

 }
}
else
{ 
echo "query not executed";
}
?>
```

but then i still failed to retrieve the data

it didnt give me any data from the database even i already set few username and useremail for it....can do for register and login,but cant retrieve it out as echo..wonder why...please anyone can help me?
result only come out this

```
query executed
sql is running
```

Comment: don't use mysql_* function as these are deprecated in php 7

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_assoc`  instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: mysqli_* give me an error
and both assoc and array is tried..still the same

Comment: you are using `mysql` driver not `mysqli`

Comment: you have a comment in your code stating, `// but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.` and you went ahead to use `mysql`

Comment: how to change the driver? sorry because i am pretty new to php

Comment: *// but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.* did you wrote this @ZhongYong

Comment: coding is download from a tutorial website bro @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @ZhongYong "For the record": The real problem here was the semi-colon in your `while` loop. It "ends" the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone is suggesting you to use mysqli instead of mysql here is the simple working example using mysqli.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "UserName: " . $row["userName"]. " Email: " . $row["userEmail"]. "<br>";
 }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Hope this works.

Comment: i wonder what this different between yours and below one...
from what i understanding,both are same just the word not same and yours is 1 code, mine is 2 codes

Comment: yes..this work..but i need to understand why below don't work but yours work...can i have the reason?

Comment: It seems you might be mixing some old codes that why I put all code in single file to make is simpler.

Comment: My pleasure, now you can use this code, and accept the ans :)

Comment: can i ask 1 more question? that is is that better if i put all code in single file? can it make the things more simpler but longer only right? will it be more complexity?

Comment: No! the best practice is to make a separate database connection file, all you need to do just include that file and use in your code.

Comment: any place to contact u anyway? like whatsapp or facebook? because i got quite some question to ask....it about my assignment that deadlines is nearby...

Comment: fb.com/kamrankhatti

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I noticed you just accepted an answer now. I needed to point out the real problem as to why your code failed to show results; *"just for the record"* and for future visitors to the question/answer.

---

The problem here is in this line:

```
while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_array($is_query_run)); // <<< semi-colon
```

Notice the ending semi-colon? It "ends" the statement and would not throw an error because it is considered as being a valid statement in PHP and other languages.

Anything inside that loop will not show up, **you need to remove it.**

The api that you used is obviously working, since there are 2 echo's showing up.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated with a semicolon** at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

You should also consider switching to either the mysqli or PDO api; the mysql_ api is in deprecation and removed as of PHP 7.

Consider looking into using a prepared statement, if and when user interaction ever comes into play.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

Edit #2:

I noticed something else while going through your code again. `'</td></tr';` is missing a `>` here and should have read as `'</td></tr>';` and unsure if you have `<table></table>` tags, unless you did not include those in your question.

If `'</td></tr';` was just a bad paste or is that part of your real code, is unknown.

If it is part of your real code, then that will break/affect the HTML as well as the output.

Comment: Note: I'm not looking for glory or added rep here, so please don't get the wrong impression. I merely wanted to point out the *real* problem/solution to this question. Even though some of the other answers may have worked, is because they removed the semi-colon in the `while` loop but did not explain the reason as to why it needed to be removed.

Comment: is removed,but still the same..is because the other page i still using the mysql..i tot that is not related...

Comment: @ZhongYong That is very odd. To think that you are getting both strings echo'd, the query loop should have echo'd the columns.

Comment: @ZhongYong I noticed something else while going through your code again. `'</td></tr';` is missing a `>` here and should have read as `'</td></tr>';` and unsure if you have `<table></table>` tags, unless you did not include those in your question. Was `'</td></tr';` just a bad paste or is that part of your real code? If so, that will break/affect your HTML and the output.

Answer (score -1):

use mysqli instead of mysql.

mysqli stands for mysql improve.

The main useful features of mysqli are:

an Object-oriented interface,
support for prepared statements,
support for multiple statements,
support for transactions,
enhanced debugging capabilities,
embedded server support.

Comment: sorry but how is this useful in fixing OP's problem?

Comment: i did change all the mysql_* to mysqli_* but it give me the error like 
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp64\www\login\dbconnect.php on line 13

Comment: @ZhongYong `mysli_*` is not a clone of `mysql_*` please consult the manual